# Altering MySQL (Percona 5.7) table fails because of duplicate entry errors

Tags: mysql, duplicates, alter-table, percona, mysql-5.7

We have updated MySQL (Percona) from 5.6 to 5.7 and we were told that some tables needs to be altered / repaired, because the 'datetime' field is different now. Altering the table fails with a duplicate entry error despite having primary key on both fields, device_id and ts and all the data seems ok (no duplicates). As far as I know primary key also must be unique.

We have tried to select the duplicate entries by 'device_id' and 'ts' conditions in the WHERE part and it finds only 1 instance of the record. When we try to select only by ts field, it finds 2 instances of the same record. How is that possible? What are those duplicates? Are the keys corrupted? Is there any other way than to create a new table and pipe all data with INSERT IGNORE there?

Edit: The error is as follows:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '486-2014-10-26 02:39:33' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Edit 2: The table structure is as follows (device_id, ts and 32 sensors):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sensor_log` (
    `device_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `D1` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `D2` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    ...
    `D30` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
    `D31` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts))
(PARTITION p_sl_2013 VALUES LESS THAN (1388530800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_sl_2014 VALUES LESS THAN (1420066800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_sl_2015 VALUES LESS THAN (1451602800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_sl_2016 VALUES LESS THAN (1483225200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_sl_2017_q1 VALUES LESS THAN (1490997600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_sl_2017_q2 VALUES LESS THAN (1498860000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_sl_2017_q3 VALUES LESS THAN (1506808800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_sl_2017_q4 VALUES LESS THAN (1514761200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_sl_2018_q1 VALUES LESS THAN (1522533600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_sl_2018_q2 VALUES LESS THAN (1530396000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_sl_2018_q3 VALUES LESS THAN (1538344800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_sl_2018_q4 VALUES LESS THAN (1546297200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_sl_2019_q1 VALUES LESS THAN (1551394800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_sl_2019_q2 VALUES LESS THAN (1556661600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_sl_2019_q3 VALUES LESS THAN (1561932000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_sl_2019_q4 VALUES LESS THAN (1567288800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_sl_2019_q5 VALUES LESS THAN (1572562800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_sl_2019_q6 VALUES LESS THAN (1577833200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_sl_X VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */;

--
-- Indexes for table `sensor_log`
--
ALTER TABLE `sensor_log`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`device_id`,`ts`);
```

Comment: Please always include full error messages as well as other useful information like the table definition. You can spare yourself a lot of writing and it avoids confusion and guess work.

Comment: I totally forgot that could also add the error. I've added it now. Also we tried to ALTER TABLE with FORCE, but the same error appears.

Answer (score 0):

When the error looks something like this:

```
ERROR 1022 (23000): Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-6b04_a0'
```

then you're probably trying to create a foreign key twice with the same name. Or something like that. Check your foreign keys.

If you want to enforce a table update to the new format, you don't have to make any changes to the table. Just do

```
ALTER TABLE foo FORCE;
```

---

EDIT:

You have duplicate entries in your table. Your primary key is spanning over two columns. Look for those duplicates with

```
SELECT device_id, ts, COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY device_id, ts
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Then you will have to clean up your table by making sure that only one entry per device_id and ts combination is present.

Comment: I've mentioned in my initial post that duplicates are not visible when selecting data by both columns in the WHERE part. Duplicates are only seen if you select only by one column, ts for instance. To be sure that's the case we have executed the SELECT query you've written above and it returned: Empty set (7 hours 53 min 38.30 sec).

Comment: When your query runs for almost 8 hours, you almost certainly haven't selected the columns that make up your primary key. Or your database runs on a USB 2.0 stick or something. And your error message tells you exactly which row it is. `486-2014-10-26 02:39:33` means `486 is the value for the first part of your primary key, the rest is the timestamp column in your primary key. Have you selected the correct columns? I can't tell, cause you're still not sharing the create table statement like I told you in the first place.

Comment: Provide every valuable information as it is, don't describe it, then people can help you much better and it avoids confusion.

Comment: I've added the table structure, partition info and primary key into the original post. Query runs 8 hours, because the table is 270 GB big and has over 2.6 billion records. We have run two queries today:

`select * from sensor_log where ts = '2014-10-26 02:39:33'` returned 2 records for device_id 486.

`select * from sensor_log where ts = '2014-10-26 02:39:33' and device_id = 486` returned 1 record.